# Capture from desktop (VFR) to mp4 - how to deal with frame rate?

Tags: c++, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I'm putting frames from the Desktop Duplication API through a Media Foundation H264 encoder transform (in this case, NVIDIA's hardware accelerated encoder) and then into a `SinkWriter` to put the frames into an MP4 container. This whole process works quite well and is extremely fast.

### The problem

The video is in slow motion, so to speak. I have the frame rates set everywhere to 60 fps, and the sample time and durations are based on that 60 fps. What is happening is that I am providing way more frames than 60 per second to the `SinkWriter`. I don't quite know how the MP4 format and video players work but I assume it is simply looking at the frame duration (16.7ms for 60fps) and since there are way more frames than 60, it appears slowed down.

I've had a very hard time finding out how to 'properly' limit the frames being provided to the encoder/sink writer. If I simply `Sleep` for 15ms or so, the video appears fine but I realize that's not the way to do it - it was just for testing and to confirm my theory. I've tried using the Frame Rate Converter DSP but it gives me an `E_UNEXPECTED` because I don't think it expects a 'live' source.

Essentially I think I need to do a variable frame rate to constant frame rate conversion.

### My question

How would you normally deal with this issue? How do you do this? Are there ways to do it with a 'live' source in Media Foundation? Or is a manual implementation required (e.g. calculating, dropping frames if faster or duplicating them if slower, etc)?

Code provided below;

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <iostream>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_4.h>
#include <dxgi1_5.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>
#include <mftransform.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <wmcodecdsp.h>
#include <evr.h>

void SetupEncoder(ID3D11Device*, IMFTransform**);
void SetupFrameRateConverter(ID3D11Device*, IMFTransform**);
void SetupSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter**);
void InitializeBuffer(IMFTransform*, MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER*, UINT32);

int main()
{
    SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);

    IDXGIFactory1* dxgiFactory;
    auto hr = CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)(&dxgiFactory));

    IDXGIAdapter* adapter = NULL;
    dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);

    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC desc = {};
    adapter->GetDesc(&desc);
    printf("GPU %d: %S (Vendor %04x Device %04x)\n", 0, desc.Description, desc.VendorId, desc.DeviceId);

    IDXGIOutput* output;
    adapter->EnumOutputs(1, &output);

    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC outputDesc = {};
    output->GetDesc(&outputDesc);

    printf("Output %S\n", outputDesc.DeviceName);

    IDXGIOutput5* dxgiOutput5;
    output->QueryInterface(&dxgiOutput5);


    // Set up D3D11
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    ID3D11Device* device;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levelChosen;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext;
    auto result = D3D11CreateDevice(adapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, featureLevels, _countof(featureLevels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, &levelChosen, &deviceContext);

    ID3D11Multithread* multithread;
    device->QueryInterface(&multithread);
    multithread->SetMultithreadProtected(true);

    // Set up output duplication
    DXGI_FORMAT formats[] =
    {
        DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
    };
    IDXGIOutputDuplication* duplication;
    result = dxgiOutput5->DuplicateOutput1(device, 0, _countof(formats), formats, &duplication);


    IMFTransform* encoder, * fpsConverter;
    IMFSinkWriter* sinkWriter;
    SetupEncoder(device, &encoder);
    SetupFrameRateConverter(device, &fpsConverter);
    SetupSinkWriter(&sinkWriter);

    // Allocate buffers
    IMFMediaType* outputType;
    fpsConverter->GetOutputCurrentType(0, &outputType);

    MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER buffer;
    DWORD status;

    UINT32 uiFrameSize = 0;
    hr = outputType->GetUINT32(MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE, &uiFrameSize);
    InitializeBuffer(fpsConverter, &buffer, uiFrameSize);

    // Event generator for async MFT
    IMFMediaEventGenerator* eventGenerator;
    encoder->QueryInterface(&eventGenerator);

    // Start up
    result = encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, NULL);
    result = encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL);
    result = encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM, NULL);

    long startTime = 0;
    long frameDuration = (long)((1 / 60.f) * 10000000);

    UINT frameCounter = 0;
    while (frameCounter < 1000)
    {
        IMFMediaEvent* mediaEvent;
        eventGenerator->GetEvent(0, &mediaEvent);

        MediaEventType eventType;
        mediaEvent->GetType(&eventType);
        if (eventType == METransformNeedInput)
        {
            // Grab frame first
            DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO frameInfo;
            IDXGIResource* screenResource;
            duplication->AcquireNextFrame(10000, &frameInfo, &screenResource);

            ID3D11Texture2D* texture;
            screenResource->QueryInterface(&texture);

            // Verify correct screen for now
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC d;
            texture->GetDesc(&d);
            assert(d.Width == 1920);

            // Create sample for it
            IMFSample* sample;
            IMFMediaBuffer* mediaBuffer;
            result = MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface(NULL, &sample);
            result = MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(IID_ID3D11Texture2D, texture, 0, TRUE, &mediaBuffer);
            result = sample->AddBuffer(mediaBuffer);


            
            ////////////////////////
            // Does not work, E_UNEXPECTED
            // Put it through the FPS converter
            /*result = fpsConverter->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
            if (FAILED(result))
                break;

            result = fpsConverter->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &buffer, &status);*/
            ///////////////////////



            sample->SetSampleDuration(frameDuration);
            sample->SetSampleTime(startTime);
            startTime += frameDuration;

            result = encoder->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);

            sample->Release();
            mediaBuffer->Release();

            ++frameCounter;

            // Important, do not forget to release frame
            duplication->ReleaseFrame();
        }
        else if (eventType == METransformHaveOutput)
        {
            MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER encodingOutputBuffer;
            encodingOutputBuffer.dwStreamID = 0;
            encodingOutputBuffer.pSample = nullptr;
            encodingOutputBuffer.dwStatus = 0;
            encodingOutputBuffer.pEvents = nullptr;
            result = encoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &encodingOutputBuffer, 0);

            // Now write to sink
            sinkWriter->WriteSample(0, encodingOutputBuffer.pSample);

            if (encodingOutputBuffer.pSample)
                encodingOutputBuffer.pSample->Release();

            if (encodingOutputBuffer.pEvents)
                encodingOutputBuffer.pEvents->Release();
        }
    }

    encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_END_OF_STREAM, NULL);
    encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_END_STREAMING, NULL);
    encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, NULL);

    result = sinkWriter->Finalize();
    sinkWriter->Release();

    duplication->Release();
    adapter->Release();
    device->Release();
}

void SetupEncoder(ID3D11Device* device, IMFTransform** encoderOut)
{
    MFStartup(MF_VERSION, MFSTARTUP_FULL);

    IMFAttributes* ptr = NULL;
    MFCreateAttributes(&ptr, 0);

    UINT token;
    IMFDXGIDeviceManager* deviceManager;
    MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&token, &deviceManager);
    deviceManager->ResetDevice(device, token);

    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO outputType;
    outputType.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
    outputType.guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_H264;

    IMFActivate** activates = NULL;
    UINT count = 0;
    MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER, NULL, &outputType, &activates, &count);

    IMFTransform* encoder;
    activates[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&encoder));

    // Release the rest
    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        activates[i]->Release();
    }

    IMFAttributes* attribs;
    encoder->GetAttributes(&attribs);

    // Required
    attribs->SetUINT32(MF_TRANSFORM_ASYNC_UNLOCK, 1);
    attribs->SetUINT32(MF_LOW_LATENCY, 1);

    LPWSTR friendlyName = 0;
    UINT friendlyNameLength;
    attribs->GetAllocatedString(MFT_FRIENDLY_NAME_Attribute, &friendlyName, &friendlyNameLength);

    printf("Using encoder %S", friendlyName);

    auto result = encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER, reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(deviceManager));

    DWORD inputStreamId, outputStreamId;
    encoder->GetStreamIDs(1, &inputStreamId, 1, &outputStreamId);

    // Set up output media type
    IMFMediaType* mediaType;
    MFCreateMediaType(&mediaType);

    mediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    mediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 10240000);
    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2);
    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
    MFSetAttributeSize(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1920, 1080);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60000, 1001);

    result = encoder->SetOutputType(outputStreamId, mediaType, 0);

    // Set up input media type
    IMFMediaType* suggestedInputType;
    result = encoder->GetInputAvailableType(inputStreamId, 0, &suggestedInputType);
    
    suggestedInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    suggestedInputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12);
    MFSetAttributeSize(suggestedInputType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1920, 1080);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(suggestedInputType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60000, 1001);

    result = encoder->SetInputType(inputStreamId, suggestedInputType, 0);

    *encoderOut = encoder;
}

void SetupFrameRateConverter(ID3D11Device* device, IMFTransform** fpsConverterTransformOut)
{
    // Set up DSP
    IMFTransform* fpsConverter;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CFrameRateConvertDmo, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMFTransform, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&fpsConverter));

    // Set up fps input type
    IMFMediaType* mediaType;
    MFCreateMediaType(&mediaType);

    UINT32 imageSize;
    MFCalculateImageSize(MFVideoFormat_ARGB32, 1920, 1080, &imageSize);

    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE, imageSize);
    mediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    mediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_ARGB32);
    MFSetAttributeSize(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1920, 1080);

    auto result = fpsConverter->SetInputType(0, mediaType, 0);

    // Set up fps output type
    MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60000, 1001);

    result = fpsConverter->SetOutputType(0, mediaType, 0);

    // Start up FPS
    fpsConverter->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL);
    fpsConverter->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM, NULL);

    *fpsConverterTransformOut = fpsConverter;
}

void SetupSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter** sinkWriterOut)
{
    IMFAttributes* attribs;
    MFCreateAttributes(&attribs, 0);

    attribs->SetUINT32(MF_LOW_LATENCY, 1);
    attribs->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, 1);
    attribs->SetGUID(MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4);
    attribs->SetUINT32(MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING, 1);

    IMFSinkWriter* sinkWriter;
    MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"output.mp4", NULL, attribs, &sinkWriter);

    // Set up input type
    IMFMediaType* mediaType;
    MFCreateMediaType(&mediaType);

    mediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    mediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 10240000);
    MFSetAttributeSize(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1920, 1080);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60000, 1001);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2);
    mediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 0);


    DWORD streamIndex;
    auto result = sinkWriter->AddStream(mediaType, &streamIndex);
    result = sinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, mediaType, NULL);

    sinkWriter->BeginWriting();

    *sinkWriterOut = sinkWriter;
}

void InitializeBuffer(IMFTransform* transform, MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER* buffer, const UINT32 frameSize)
{
    MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO outputStreamInfo;
    DWORD outputStreamId = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&outputStreamInfo, sizeof(outputStreamInfo));
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(*buffer));

    auto hr = transform->GetOutputStreamInfo(outputStreamId, &outputStreamInfo);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if ((outputStreamInfo.dwFlags & MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES) == 0 &&
            (outputStreamInfo.dwFlags & MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES) == 0) {

            IMFSample* pOutputSample = NULL;
            IMFMediaBuffer* pMediaBuffer = NULL;

            hr = MFCreateSample(&pOutputSample);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(frameSize, &pMediaBuffer);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = pOutputSample->AddBuffer(pMediaBuffer);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                buffer->pSample = pOutputSample;
                buffer->pSample->AddRef();
            }

            pMediaBuffer->Release();
            pOutputSample->Release();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Stream provides samples";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AcquireNextFrame is a copy from what has changed, not a screeenshot. You cannot acquire frames faster than your monitor's refresh rate (60hz => 60ps max). The "I am providing way more frames than 60 per second" statement seems strange. Also, MF's sample duration should correspond to reality, not a fixed value. For a screen that doesn't change (mouse is in question, should it matter or not), the sample duration can be long.